# side-by-side divs not working in FF

Tags: css, html, css-position

Ok, I have finally got my divs to sit nicely side-by-side in a parent div.

But....I can not seem to put a margin between them. Sample of code is [here](http://www.serco-hrc.com/divPositioning/home.html).  The two ids/divs in question are importInfo and newDevelopment.  Both are absolute positioned with tops at 0 and left/right at 0 (respectively), widths at 50%.  These two divs need to be fluid so that they extend vertically when the user adjusts their browser window horizontally.  I need someone to point out my dumb mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because they're not positioned correctly. Margins, padding, and border are by default not included in the calculation of the box's width. This is how your box actually appears on the page:

[image: Incorrect positioning]

You really shouldn't be using absolute positioning for something as simple as this. Try setting both of the boxes as `display: table-cell` instead or find another more suitable solution to position the boxes next to each other.

Comment: Thank you.  This works ok.  I found out that I had to take the parent of these two divs and make them "display: table-row" for things to render correctly.  Thanks for the suggestion.  This was a display setting that I had not used.